# SQLAlchemy how to use OR on filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use an OR on this query:

```
User.query.filter(or_(username==data['username'], email==data['email'])).first()
```

But, I get this message:

> global name 'or_' is not defined

I'm using SqlAlchemy 0.9.7 (it already includes [or_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_))

Anyone encountered this before and/or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Did you `from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import or_`?

Comment: `import flask.ext.sqlalchemy`

Comment: @thaavik individually importing the method fixed that issue.

Comment: How is this "out of topic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you did not import the necessary module

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
```

Also, I'm not sure if this operator can be used with a filter. But try this approach.

> The or_() conjunction is also available using the Python | operator (though note that compound expressions need to be parenthesized in order to function with Python operator precedence behavior):

```
User.query.filter((username==data['username']) | (email==data['email'])).first()
```

Comment: individually importing the method fixed that issue, although I don't know why it would not be included with the entire library.